# How does modernizr check support for the new input attributes in webforms2.0?

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

Well, that's pretty much my whole question. I can see how they check for CSS3-support, trying to fetch `style.borderRadius` and such to see if the browser knows what the heck is going on. But since most browsers will let the attribute stay (`<input type="date">`), but still not support it fully, I can't understand how they do their magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each input type it's different, mostly:
http://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master//modernizr.js#L699-751

I think the inline comments describe the considerations for each, so... I'll direct you there. :)

But the first thing we do is do `elem.value = ':)'` and see if that sticks. If it does, then it's an indication the feature isn't in place.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the detection of date, datetime, etc using this method in Chromium 15 and the above test fails. I have updated the code and submitted it here: https://github.com/buzypi/Modernizr/blob/patch-1/modernizr.js and created a pull request here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/439